# guidance for newbie

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have just started to learn ROS. I went through the ROS tutorials and I've understood the basic ideas. However, I find myself lost when I want to create a new program. I want to work on the turtlebot, so I want to try out programs on gazebo.
Is there a sample code/ step by step procedure out there for a simple application, say, moving the turtlebot ahead by a predefined distance? Its just that I don't know where to start from. Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63299/guidance-for-newbie/) by [turtlebotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4957/turtlebotnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-23**:
@turtlebotnewbie please read the ROS and gazebo tutorials, they are good enough

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-05-30**:
Just as an advice, maybe, if you want to use gazebo, you should better go with ROS fuerte version since there has been many feedbacks about gazebo not working well with groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial about gazebo part on ROS website is kind of outdated. So please go check the gazebo official website. in the gazebosim wiki tutorials. I think you will find out what you need there. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [AllenZhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5024/allenzhang/) with karma: 26 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1